# Errors installing vue/cliapp under docker

Tags: docker, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I want to install my @vue/cli 4.0.5 app under docker and using https://medium.com/@jwdobken/vue-with-docker-initialize-develop-and-build-51fad21ad5e6 link : 
I modified the command line : modified node source from 11-alpine and renamed project name and installed the project, but running command

```
yarn serve
```

I got error that serve was not found :

```
me@athoe:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/VApps/DOCKER_TEST$ mkdir vtaskproject && cd "$_" && docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/$(basename `pwd`)" -w "/$(basename `pwd`)" -it node:11-alpine sh -c "yarn global add @vue/cli && vue create ."
Unable to find image 'node:11-alpine' locally
11-alpine: Pulling from library/node

e7c96db7181b: Already exists 
0119aca44649: Pull complete 
40df19605a18: Pull complete 
82194b8b4a64: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:8bb56bab197299c8ff820f1a55462890caf08f57ffe3b91f5fa6945a4d505932
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:11-alpine

yarn global v1.15.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > vue-cli-plugin-apollo > apollo > git-parse > babel-polyfill > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > vue-cli-plugin-apollo > apollo > git-parse > babel-polyfill > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
warning Your current version of Yarn is out of date. The latest version is "1.21.1", while you're on "1.15.2".
info To upgrade, run the following command:
$ curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
success Installed "@vue/cli@4.1.1" with binaries:
      - vue
Done in 32.17s.
?  Your connection to the default yarn registry seems to be slow.
   Use https://registry.npm.taobao.org for faster installation? Yes


Vue CLI v4.1.1
? Generate project in current directory? Yes


Vue CLI v4.1.1
? Please pick a preset: default (babel, eslint)
? Pick the package manager to use when installing dependencies: Yarn


Vue CLI v4.1.1
���  Creating project in /vtaskproject.
���  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

yarn install v1.15.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.


success Saved lockfile.
Done in 77.43s.
����  Invoking generators...
����  Installing additional dependencies...

yarn install v1.15.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Saved lockfile.
Done in 24.82s.
���  Running completion hooks...

����  Generating README.md...

����  Successfully created project vtaskproject.
����  Get started with the following commands:

 $ yarn serve

me@athoe:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/VApps/DOCKER_TEST/vtaskproject$ yarn serve
00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'serve'
serge@athoe:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/VApps/DOCKER_TEST/vtaskproject$ yarn --version
0.32
```

I see that on successfull installation newly created project dir was selected.

Also in the provided article next was :

> Dockerfile The Dockerfile is identical to the given example in the
>   documentation. Only the build-stage is split up into an install-stage
>   and a build-stage, since we don’t need to build when we are
>   developing!

But the thin is I do not see any Dockerfile file in the created project : https://i.stack.imgur.com/09IYC.jpg  as I expected.
Had Dockerfile be there and how move next ?

```
$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
4.15.0-72-generic
x86_64
$ docker --version 
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run that very long-winded `docker run` command to bootstrap your project?  I'd suggest shelving Docker at this point in your development cycle: install Node and Yarn on your host without Docker, and then you can run your `yarn add` and `vue create` commands without doing any special setup.

Comment: Could you please provide more details or related article?

Comment: On most desktop systems you can just install them using your local package manager; on my Mac I can `brew install node yarn`.  From there pretty much any tutorial should work unmodified.